# is it possible to set an "intended" response code from a delegating handler?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

So in our old WCF rest service, we had a helper class that would look at a response object and run an interface member GetStatus to retrieve a status code which it would then set to the WebOperationContext. In web api, this is no longer possible, so we're looking into `DelegatingHandler` to possible set this. Here's the scenario:

Not all POSTs will result in a `201 - Created` code. For instance, some are used for GET type operations with complex parameters. However, some POST operations WILL result in a 201. In our response objects, we have an interface called `IResult` which has a method `GetResult()` which returns an HttpStatus code that gets set in the business logic being run during the operation. So if we were to run a service operation (post)

`var result = AdvancedSearch(myPayload);`

and then run `result.GetResult()`, it would return an `HttpStatus` of 200. However, if we were to run

`var result = AddNewUser(myPayload);`

and then run `result.GetResult()`; it would return an `HttpStatus` of 201

Right now, in these operations that should return a 201, i simply create a new response object from the `request.CreateResponse(...)`; method in the controller itself. However, the some of the more senior guys on the team don't like it. They want something central to handle this. Something similar to what we had before.

Since there is no global context for setting the response code, I figured that I'd try to accomplish this through creating a `DelegatingHandler`. I know that you can work on the response in the `Continue` method, however, I'm not sure that this is going to be possible. I realize that this method runs in a different pipeline, outside of the actual MVC framework; I don't see any way to retrieve the response payload from the `HttpResponseMessage` and run the `GetResult()` method from the `IResult` interface.

Is this possible? Is there some other way to do this? Am I stuck setting there response in the controller (I'm ok with that, actually. I'm just doing my due diligence).

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extension on HttpResponseMessage called "TryGetContentValue", which you could use to get the response content before it gets serialized by the formatters.